# What is the best way to generate KML files in C#?

Tags: c#, kml, google-earth

What is the best way to generate KML files using C#?

Is there a class library that I can use? I have looked and struggled to find anything interesting.

libkml doesn't have a C# implementation or wrapper.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 16):

[SharpKML - library based on Google's C++ implementation of libkml](http://sharpkml.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Here's the github link to SharpKML: https://github.com/samcragg/sharpkml

Answer (score 3):

Here are ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​some:

- http://code.google.com/p/kml-library/
- <strike>http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Google_Earth_KML_Files.aspx</strike>
- http://gekml.boseefus.com/

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd link seem to be dead.

Comment: they dont seem to be dead they ARE dead

Comment: And your first link points to libkml which, as stated in the question, doesn't have an interop wrapper

Comment: Indignantly followed the link in high dudgeon, but you are correct - I must have been really tired the first time I looked. My apologies. Have you tried that implementation? What's the quality like?